# Activity wont start in Android application project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-virtual-device

I am using Eclipse and I am building an Android application. I have created a new Android application project in which I created a blank activity(just check the checkbox). The application is a basic Hello World, I have made no changes to the application that was created by default. I start the application by clicking run as -> Android Application. The Android Virtual Device starts, but the activity does not. Any ideas what might be wrong.

This is the console output:

```
[2012-10-31 06:39:28 - newand] ------------------------------
[2012-10-31 06:39:28 - newand] Android Launch!
[2012-10-31 06:39:28 - newand] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-31 06:39:28 - newand] Performing com.example.newand.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-31 06:39:28 - newand] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'androidEMP'
[2012-10-31 06:39:28 - newand] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'androidEMP'
```

Comment: Does the app at least get installed on the AVD?

Comment: I dont think so, the above is the only output.

Comment: its not problem with your application. just close the avd and run the app again

Comment: try creating a new AVD and then run the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the AVD is started but fails to load the application. Try starting the avd first and then running the application within it.

If it still fails, you can to try restarting the adb server from the command line (you need to have installed the adb tools for this) :

```
 adb kill-server
 adb start-server
```

Sometimes another AVD will open even if one is active. In that case, Close the old avd and let the new one be open. Then try killing and restarting the adb server.

Comment: The problem is that when I run the application a new avd opens, even there is one allready running.

Answer (score -1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file add entry something as

```
    <activity android:name=".yourActivityName">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Inside application tag.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: yup my bad...didn't read the console output properly..

skipped the Performing com.example.newand.MainActivity activity launch.. :)